# I'm 532 hours away from GMT?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, timezone, nsdateformatter

iPhone, Xcode, Objective-c:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *s = @"1902-02-01 01:00:00";
NSDate *aDate = [df dateFromString:s];
NSLog(@"(%@)", aDate);

// (1902-02-01 01:00:00 -053211)
```

Wow.. 532 hour timezone offset?

Comment: I think it's actually 532 hours and 11 minutes... not that that's any better... http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/description

Comment: What version of Xcode and the iPhone SDK are you running? I cannot reproduce this behavior.

Comment: @Felixyz: She also has 0 votes >_>

Comment: This question is for 'programming only'.
(Like 1000s of users... I don't play the votes/accepts/badges game.  I couldn't care less about how 'smart' or 'dumb' everyone thinks I am.  All that non-sense should be removed from SOF.com)

Comment: I'm using Xcode v3.1.4.  And get that "weird timezone offset" on the simulator.   It just crashed my v3.1.3 iPhone 3G.  What do *YOU* get when you run my code?  A correct timezone offset?